# Define task / step and run it many times / alternative to include_tasks

Tags: ansible

I have a task which I want to run many times throughout my play

```
e.g.
    - name: run_many
      debug:
        msg: "I have been run"
```

Now rather than adding this step is there a way I can pre-can / define this so I can just say:

```
- < run this pre-defined step >
```

The reason for this is I need to run this many times and I don't want to have to update it in x number of places should it ever need changing.

At the moment I am doing an include_tasks: which is, obviously, adding that to my output as a step - but is this the best / standard way to do something like this?

current setup that works:

```
$ls ./roles/demo/tasks/
main.yml  run_many.yml
$cat main.yml    
---

-  include_tasks: run_many.yml
-  include_tasks: run_many.yml
```

Play output:

```
TASK [demo: include_tasks] *******************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ansible/roles/demo/tasks/main.yml:3
included: /home/ansible/roles/demo/tasks/run_many.yml for localhost

TASK [demo: run_many] ************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ansible/roles/demo/tasks/run_many.yml:1
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "I have been run"
}

TASK [demo: include_tasks] *******************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ansible/roles/demo/tasks/main.yml:4
included: /home/ansible/roles/demo/tasks/run_many.yml for localhost

TASK [demo: run_many] ************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ansible/roles/demo/tasks/run_many.yml:1
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "I have been run"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the task you want to perform. 
For example if you want to make config changes to linux apache and then restart apache 
and you have multiple such changes then it makes no sense to put restart logic in a yml and call it using `- include`

Instead, use handlers,
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change

`notify: <handler name>` will help in triggering a handler.

Note: handler name should be same as the task name to be triggered from the handlers directory or if you define handlers normally.
/handlers/tasks/main.yml

```
  - name: OS handler
    debug: msg='test'
    when: ansible_distribution == "RedHat"
```

you can let it run a check on some global variable and call it every task using notify. It will run the check and execute if the check is success

Instead of `ansible_distribution` you can have some other global variable

Otherwise use `- include`
Let me know if this answers your question

Comment: Yes - I thought about using handlers but this needs to be run all the time and handlers only fire on a condition and didn't seem like an improvement. My step is a 'get current status' check so in my run_many I'm registering the result and checking it in the next step. It'd be better if I could say:  -name: step    when: <run get status and check the var> - without having to do it before that step

Comment: you can have the condition defined in the handler logic.Check my updated Response

Comment: Hi,Yes I want this to run always though and I then take the output and use it in the when conditional of the next step. But instead of doing: include > run when:  I wondered if it was possible to run the handler at the when stage / pre-step. Nevermind